# How to create method that will generate random special character

Tags: java, selenium, random, automation

In my automation I have a input where if I enter spl character it will give an error, now I want to pass spl character randomly as element.sendkeys() to verify that it gives an error.
can anyone help me to create random method for that?

Comment: Try Apache RandomStringutils: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html#random-int-char...-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I under stand what you are trying to do, then creating and calling `randomChar();` should give you a random special character from the array `spl[]`. You can add mpre characters to the array if you wish.

```
public static char randomChar(){
    char spl[] = "!@#$%^&*()".toCharArray(); 
    // Or char spl[] = {'!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*'. '(', ')'};



    Random r = new Random();
    int Low = 0;
    int High = spl.length + 1;
    int Result = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;

    return spl[Result];

}
```

Example usage:

```
char c = randomChar();
System.out.println("By calling randomChar(), we got the character '" + c + "'");
```

you can also use it without assigning a variable its value:

```
System.out.println(randomChar());
```

Comment: @user6939 no problem! Anytime =) (Don't forget to give me an upvote ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You could populate the `ArrayList` with the needed characters and then retrieve them by positions generated randomly (e.g. using `Math` class).

Answer (score 0):

Try Following:

```
String allLetters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ01234567890";
String randomString;

    do{

        randomString=null;

        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        char c = (char) (randomGenerator.nextInt(0xB4 - 21 + 1) + 21);

        randomString= "" + c;


    }while(allLetters.contains(randomString));


    System.out.println("Generated random special charactor" + randomString);
```